# How to center horizontally an element in ionic

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I want to center an element in ionic horizontally with the same margin on the left and right

```html
<div class="tabs-group" class="ion-justify-content-center">

  <ion-row>
    <ion-col *ngFor="let i of tabsName,let j = index" size="4" (click)="switchToTabs(tabsindicator[j])" [ngClass]="tabs[tabsindicator[j]] ? 'primary-button' : 'secondary-button'">
      <ion-grid>
        <ion-row>
        </ion-row>
        <ion-row>
          <ion-col>
            <b>{{tabsName[j]}} </b>
          </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
      </ion-grid>
    </ion-col>

  </ion-row>

</div>
```

ion-justify-content-center ionic CSS class is not applying centering , this is the output :

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use `ion-justify-content-center` on a flexbox node. So either you put `display: flex` on your wrapper div node, or you just use `ion-justify-content-center` on `<ion-row>` like so.

```
<ion-row class="ion-justify-content-center">
      <ion-col>
        <b>{{tabsName[j]}} </b>
      </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

Answer (score 0):

`<ion-grid style="height: 100%"> <ion-row justify-content-center align-items-center style="height: 100%; flex-direction: column"> <div text-center> <ion-icon name="images" style="zoom:5.0;" color="medium"></ion-icon> <h4>No Image Found</h4> <p>Looks like there are no converted image available at this moment, Please click <b> <ion-icon name="git-compare" color="medium" style="zoom:2.0;"></ion-icon> </b> button to convert a image</p> </div> </ion-row> </ion-grid>`

https://codevampires.com/place-content-horizontally-vertically-in-center-ionic4/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).